# How can I stop tinyMCE from remembering last window size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, tinymce

I've tried using the settings below in the init but tinyMCE continues to remember the last window size set.

```
theme_advanced_resizing: true,
theme_advanced_resizing_use_cookies : false,
```

I'm setting the size each time I init with dynamic values, the values are being passed as I can see them in the console if I output them.

Here is the complete init code...

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#eContent",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    theme_advanced_resizing_use_cookies : false,
    plugins: "autolink,wordcount",
    format: false,
    toolbar: "undo redo,bold italic",
    menubar: false,
    width: eWidth,
    height: eHeight,

});
```

Comment: Without seeing some working code nobody will be able to tell you what is happening.  If you are using TinyMCE 4 `theme_advanced_resizing` is not a valid option (it existed for TinyMCE 3).  Perhaps you could create a MCVE for us to look at (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Well, I'm using version 4. How can I provide a working example of something that I'm unable to get working? The point of my question is to acquire a working example from someone who knows how to disable tinyMCE from remembering the last used size.

Comment: You appear to be passing size in via variables `width: eWidth, height: eHeight,` in your configuration.  Seeing how you are doing that and how you are trying to change the values would be what would help.  I suspect that you have a JavaScript scope issue but can't really say without seeing the code that you have implemented so far.

Comment: If it were a scope issue, it wouldn't be sizing correctly the first time. On the second, third, etc. the exact same element fails to resize. From everything I've read it's due to tinymce caching the size. I'm now trying to destroy the tinymce instance and init again. I think since the instance is initialized that it won't change size and is ignoring the "new" init.

Comment: "I think since the instance is initialized that it won't change size and is ignoring the "new" init".  You are correct - once you init the editor there are a variety of things that cannot be modified unless you remove() the editor and re-initialize it.  Your answer below is the correct way to address what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation Michael! I couldn't find any "on the fly" sizing functions in the tinyMCE 4 API. It would be awesome if they addressed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this code and it seems to work as expected.

```
if ( tinymce.get('editor_id') !== null ) {
    tinymce.get('editor_id').remove();
}
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#editor_id",
    plugins: "autolink,wordcount",
    format: false,
    toolbar: "undo redo,bold italic",
    menubar: false,
    width: eWidth,
    height: eHeight,

});
```

Since the tinyMCE instance already existed on the second, third, etc. call, It wouldn't size using another init. I just destroyed the instance if it existed. There is probably a way to set the size after it's initialized, but this is working for me, so until I learn the other way this will be my solution.